# Populating a list of lists with random items

Tags: python

I have a list of lists with a certain range:

```
l = [["this", "is", "a"], ["list", "of"], ["lists", "that", "i", "want"], ["to", "copy"]]
```

And a list of words:

```
words = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "id", "sint", "risus", "per", "ut", "enim", "velit", "nunc", "ultricies"]
```

I need to create an exact replica of the list of lists, but with random terms picked from the other list.

This was the first thing that came to mind, but no dice.

```
for random.choice in words:
  for x in list:
    for y in x:
      y = random.choice
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show your two input lists, plus some sample output. Right now it's a little difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Isn't this just shuffling?

Comment: you do realize that `==` is an equality check, not an assignment, right?

Comment: Do you mean you want to shuffle your list? If you pick random items from your original list, and put them in another lists, it sounds like they will not be exact replicas.

Comment: @Rawing, sorry, done!

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes, my bad, already changed it!

Comment: @ChristianDean, the only thing that i want from the list of lists is its 'matricial structural range'... i don't know if i'm making myself clear though...

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid naming variables after reserved keywords - such as `list` - in Python (or any other language)

Comment: @ktdrv, oh i don't, it was just for the sake of exemplification :) but i get you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions for this:

```
import random
my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6]]
words = ['hello', 'Python']

new_list = [[random.choice(words) for y in x] for x in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['Python', 'Python', 'hello'], ['Python', 'hello']]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new_list = []
for x in my_list:
    subl = []
    for y in x:
        subl.append(random.choice(words))
    new_list.append(subl)
```

With your example data:

```
my_list = [['this', 'is', 'a'], ['list', 'of'], 
           ['lists', 'that', 'i', 'want'], ['to', 'copy']]

words = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet', 'id', 'sint', 'risus',
         'per', 'ut', 'enim', 'velit', 'nunc', 'ultricies']
new_list = [[random.choice(words) for y in x] for x in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[['enim', 'risus', 'sint'], ['dolor', 'lorem'], ['sint', 'nunc', 'ut', 'lorem'], ['ipsum', 'amet']]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, works like a charm. I had the right direction, but with poor execution :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not storing the values back into your lists. Try:

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    subl = list[i]
    for n in range(0, len(subl)):
        list[i][n] = random.choice(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should flatten your list of lists, then shuffle, then rebuild.  Example:

```
import random

def super_shuffle(lol):
  sublist_lengths = [len(sublist) for sublist in lol]
  flat = [item for sublist in lol for item in sublist]
  random.shuffle(flat)
  pos = 0
  shuffled_lol = []
  for length in sublist_lengths:
    shuffled_lol.append(flat[pos:pos+length])
    pos += length
  return shuffled_lol

print super_shuffle([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]])
```

Prints:

```
[[7, 8, 5, 6], [9, 1, 3], [2, 4]]
```

This randomizes across ALL the lists, not just within a single sublist and guarantees no dups.